# disable logon to active directory with a blank password

Tags: active-directory

I have set up Active Directory on a Windows Server 2012R2 instance. I have written a basic application which I use to authenticate to the AD. Basic authentication works, but I noticed that I am able to authenticate even with an **empty password field**. The application which I have written first binds using credentials of a service account and then I try to authenticate using the credentials provided to the application. I do get an error if I provide an incorrect password, but an empty password still logs me in.

I have read up a bit on the **PASSWD_NOTREQD** field of the user and I tried changing it to false, but I am still getting logged in. What are the required steps to change this?

Answer (score 2):

Use GPO to set a minimum password length for the domain and then flag everyone's password to be changed at next logon to ensure that the change happens immediately. Update your service accounts, etc, manually.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've configured it manually, empty passwords are not allowed in AD by default (and the flag you mentioned is only half of the required configuration - the other is in the AD Configuration partition).

IMHO it has something to do with your implementation, so you question should be in StackOverflow.